# Hibernate JPA compliant

Tags: hibernate

In this article on thserverside.com:
http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=42651
It mentions :"JBoss has released Hibernate 3.2, their popular persistence engine, now certified compliant with the Java Persistence API."
What does this mean : "now certified compliant with the Java Persistence API."
Was not the old Hibernate (or for that matter any ORM tool) built as an implementation of JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no JPA during initial days of Hibernate. Hibernate is the first (purely my opinion) open source library that brought ORM to the main stream Java development. JPA spec came much after the Hibernate was released. Hibernate naturally also implemented the spec and it still can support Hibernate specific annotations. Now you can mix JPA+Hibernate stuff together in 1 single app by making Hibernate the JPA provider.

Comment: Thanks.So what is the difference between JPA compliant Hibernate and old Hibernate? From what I understand, the old one has no annotiaions, but then again annotations are not related to JPA

Comment: If you use JPA compliant annotations/xml cfg etc then you can switch the persistent provider to EclipseLink or OpenJPA without changing anything as you are working against the spec. JPA defined standard annotations and Hibernate also has its own annotations